# Change store id value

Tags: database, mysql, store-id

I'm working on a store with one store which has store id = 1. I want to write a db query that will update this id to something else (say 9 for example). Which table should I look for to edit this and will I need to update any other tables that may already have used the store id for cross referencing purposes such as with products and categories related tables?

Any hints on the tables I should look at and with the query would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should update only the table `core_store`.
All the other tables have constraints to the `core_store` table with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.
You have to look in the `MyISAM` tables for store id references and update those.
For example `catalogsearch_fulltext`.
But please back up before changing anything.

Comment: When you mention ON UPDATE CASCADE do you mean I need to set that up or is it already done?

Comment: @ThomasRyan. Sorry for being unclear. That should already be setup. But I've seen some migrations gone wrong and some constraints were lost. Just check if you have them. For example check the tables `catalog_product_entity_*`.

Comment: I've decided to change the order increment id's as this will be sufficient for what I need. You're answer gave me enough info to know my approach wouldn't work so I'm accepting. Fyi on my install cascade didn't apply to the store_id though. I will post my solution with a description as an answer also once I get it working.

Comment: Hey Marius, I know this was a while ago, would this work, do you think for 2.2.4?

Comment: @John. I don't know.

Comment: In M2 you can do the same except one additional place not wired with foreign keys where you also have to change it manually. It's a `default_store_id` field in `store_group` table.